# how to print javascript variable to html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

```
<script language="javascript">var str = "test"; </script>
```

I want to print it to a h2 tag in my html

```
<h2 id="header2"> </h2>
```

I have tried using `document.write (str)`;

I have also tried `document.getElementById("header2").innerHTML = str;`

but nothing worked

Comment: Is the `<script>` tag before the closing `</body>` tag?

Comment: It's always good to provide a toy example of your attempts, e.g. on http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Both of those should have worked. Try providing a more complete example and looking at your JS error console for clues.

Comment: Your code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/LZSUE/

Comment: Your code is absolutely fine, perhaps you're running it at the wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your JavaScript is executing before the DOM has loaded, so `document.getElementById("header2")` throws an error, hence why your script won't work.

You can ensure that the DOM has been loaded before you execute JavaScript by wrapping it in an `onload` event, like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // Do something
}
```

Another option is to put your script element below your body element, so that the script isn't run until everything above it is loaded. I recommend always doing this so that the page isn't "locked up" waiting for your JavaScript to load, but it's not necessarily a future-proof way of ensuring that the DOM has been loaded. I don't think any current browsers do this, but one in the future may not load the DOM from top to bottom, which would break your script.

So my suggestion is to structure your HTML file something like this:

```
<body>
<h2 id="header"></h2>
</body>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var str = "test";
    document.getElementById("header2").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not worked because you try to assign value before "header2" h2 tag created. you must write javascript code after that.

In this case you can write your code as below :

```
<h2 id="header2"> </h2>
<script language="javascript">
    var str = "test";
    document.getElementById("header2").innerHTML=str; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine here:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRUgt/1/)**

HTML:

```
<h2 id="header2"></h2>
```

JavaScript:

```
var str = "Test";

document.getElementById("header2").innerHTML = str;
```

In a full html page it would look like this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h2 id="header2"></h2>
    <script>
      var str = "Test";
      document.getElementById("header2).innerHTML = str;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Make sure your `<script>` appears AFTER your `<h2>` tag.

Comment: If you can't reproduce a problem, then don't answer it: Leave a comment and vote to close it as unreproducible.

Comment: Isn't this the same answer as @prabhat? Let's keep it clean guys

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear

Make sure that the html DOM is loaded fully then your script comes down

Other option if your script is in the head is to make sure the DOM is fully loaded by using: `window.load()` or using jQuery `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Another shot. Really? What's the definition of SO?

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onload = function() {

 document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'str';


}
```

you need to wait until the page loads

Comment: Because this is adding code that isn't needed. Their current code works fine it's likely that they're just executing it at the wrong place

Comment: this code is better than writing scripts at the bottom of the page imho, I know that jQuery document.ready is better, but this is a fast, simple javascript solution that will work in most browsers

Comment: I'm against the downvoters,  your code is elegant and shows that you waited for window to load, +1 from me

Comment: I understand, however his code is already working just executed in the wrong place i would imagine. Therefore, while this works, the .onload isn't technically needed

Comment: the OP didn't said anything about waiting until the document is ready or write code at the bottom...so I offered my solution

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the html tag is declared before you write the script
You DOM element must be loaded before the script starts. For that you can write script later.

```
<body>
<h2 id="header2"> </h2>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = "test";
document.getElementById("header2").innerHTML = str;
</script>
```

Or you can also write this code in document.ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("header2").innerHTML = str;
});
```

Comment: @A1rPun Can you please read the answer again, it is written in "OR". As an other option.

Comment: @PrabhatJain That's the information overload, and that's not good :)

Comment: @Dipaks This answer is just helping the person in solving his problem. I just wanted to gave a better approach. Now I ask you, Is it really bad ?

Comment: jQuery can never be a better approach over JavaScript when the OP hasn't asked for it

Comment: He may not be aware of it, that's why I wanted to mention that. I don't think giving a descriptive answer is really offensive :)